# Redefining the `\par` command

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I'm working on a collection of latin verses (from Ennius's *Annales*).

I defined some commands and an environment to number them, but I'm not able to center automatically the last verse. I know that redefining the `\par` command isn't such a good idea and the problem comes surely from there.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, latin]{minimal}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

% Convert arabic number to roman number
\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum#1<1
        \ifnum#1=0
        o%
        \else
            -\romannumeral -#1%
        \fi
        \else
        \romannumeral #1%
        \fi}}

% Fragment number
\newcounter{frammento}
\newcommand{\framm}{%
    \stepcounter{frammento}%
    \centering\Romannum\theframmento
    }

% Environment for fragments
\newenvironment{frammpar}{%
    \smallskip
    \def\par{%
        \vspace{1em}%
        \pdfprimitive\par\framm%
        \pdfprimitive\par\centering%
        }%

    }%
    {%
        \newline%
    }

\begin{document}
        \begin{frammpar}
        Musae quae pedibus magnum pulsatis Olympum

        Musas quas memorant, nosce nos esse \textit{Camenas}

        Nam latos populos res atque po\"emata nostra cluebant

        somno leni placidoque revinctus
    \end{frammpar}
\end{document}
```

And then the result:
[image: Compiled result.]

What's the problem and what's the best way to solve it?

Comment: redefining `\par`  is almost certainly going to break something, It's also very fragile if done this way for example if you have two blank lines instead of one normally this is fine but here gives two headings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I woudl avoid redefining `\par` completely:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, latin]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}


% Fragment number
\newcounter{frammento}
\newcommand{\framm}{%
    \par
    \refstepcounter{frammento}%
    \addvspace{1em}%
    \centering
    {\everypar{}\Roman{frammento}\par\noindent}
    }

% Environment for fragments
\newenvironment{frammpar}{%
    \par
    \smallskip
    \centering
    \everypar{\framm}%
    }%
    {%
     \par
    }

\begin{document}


        \begin{frammpar}

        Musae quae pedibus magnum pulsatis Olympum


% note multiple blank lines



        Musas quas memorant, nosce nos esse \textit{Camenas}

        Nam latos populos res atque po\"emata nostra cluebant

        somno leni placidoque revinctus
    \end{frammpar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a `\pdfprimitive\par` instead of the `\newline` at the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, latin]{minimal}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

% Convert arabic number to roman number
\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum#1<1
        \ifnum#1=0
        o%
        \else
            -\romannumeral -#1%
        \fi
        \else
        \romannumeral #1%
        \fi}}

% Fragment number
\newcounter{frammento}
\newcommand{\framm}{%
    \stepcounter{frammento}%
    \centering\Romannum\theframmento
    }

% Environment for fragments
\newenvironment{frammpar}{%
    \smallskip
    \def\par{%
        \vspace{1em}%
        \pdfprimitive\par\framm%
        \pdfprimitive\par\centering%
        }%

    }%
    {%
        %\newline%
        \pdfprimitive\par
    }

\begin{document}
        \begin{frammpar}
        Musae quae pedibus magnum pulsatis Olympum

        Musas quas memorant, nosce nos esse \textit{Camenas}

        Nam latos populos res atque po\"emata nostra cluebant

        somno leni placidoque revinctus
    \end{frammpar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Save the original `\par` definition at the invocation of `frammpar` and then use that to close out the environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, latin]{minimal}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

% Convert arabic number to roman number
\newcommand{\Romannum}[1]{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum#1<1
        \ifnum#1=0
        o%
        \else
            -\romannumeral -#1%
        \fi
        \else
        \romannumeral #1%
        \fi}}

% Fragment number
\newcounter{frammento}
\newcommand{\framm}{%
    \stepcounter{frammento}%
    \centering\Romannum\theframmento
    }

% Environment for fragments
\newenvironment{frammpar}{%
    \smallskip
    \let\oldpar\par%
    \def\par{%
        \vspace{1em}%
        \pdfprimitive\par\framm%
        \pdfprimitive\par\centering%
        }%

    }%
    {%
        \oldpar%
    }

\begin{document}
        \begin{frammpar}
        Musae quae pedibus magnum pulsatis Olympum

        Musas quas memorant, nosce nos esse \textit{Camenas}

        Nam latos populos res atque po\"emata nostra cluebant

        somno leni placidoque revinctus
    \end{frammpar}
\end{document}
```

[image]